# comparing columns of files in unix?

Tags: python, shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to compare filenames of Today.txt with Main.txt.
If there is match, then print all 6 columns of matched file of Main.txt with a new file say matched.txt.

and the files which are not matched with Main.txt, then list the filename and time of TODAY.txt in a new file say unmatched.txt

NOTE: Plus sign(+) indicates files are from inprogress directory,sometimes filenames are appended with "+".

Main.txt

```
 date      filename          timestamp space  count   status
Nov 4    +CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time
```

Today.txt

```
 filename       time
CHCK01_20161104.txt 06:03
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
AR01_20161104.txt   09:36
AR02_20161104.txt   09:36
ifs01_20161104.txt  21:16
TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:16
```

Required Output:
matched.txt

```
Nov 4    +CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time
```

unmatched.txt

```
CHCK05_20161104.txt 11:10
CHCK09_20161104.txt 21:46
ifs01_20161104.txt  21:16
```

Below command gives me proper output except when the files are appended with plus(+) sign.

```
 awk 'FNR==1{next} 
  NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} 
  $3 in a{print; delete a[$3]} 
      END{for(k in a) print k,a[k] > "unmatched"}' today main > matched
```

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line `$3 in a` while running on the `main` file. For the string value with `+` to be matched, use `gensub` on `$3` during the operation which is available in `GNU awk`. The importance of `gensub` over `gsub` is that it returns the value of replacement than reflecting on the file. So using it for your case as

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{next} 
  NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} 
  gensub(/+/,"",1,$3) in a{print; delete a[gensub(/+/,"",1,$3)]} 
      END{for(k in a) print k,a[k] > "unmatched"}' today main 

Nov 4    +CHCK01_20161104.txt  06:39   2.15M  17153    on_time
Nov 4    TRIPS11_20161104.txt 09:03   0.00M  24       On_Time
Nov 4    AR02_20161104.txt    09:31   0.00M  7        On_Time
Nov 4    AR01_20161104.txt    09:31   0.04M  433      On_Time
```

produces the 4 lines in output as you need.

From the `gawk` manual page.

```
gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target])
           gensub is a general substitution function. Like sub and gsub, it 
searches the target string target for matches of the regular expression regexp. Unlike sub and gsub, 
the modified string is returned as the result of the function, and the original target string
is not changed. If how is a string beginning with `g' or `G', then it replaces all matches 
of regexp with replacement.
```

So in our case, `gensub(/+/,"",1,$3)`, replaces first occurrence of `+` with an empty string only from in beginning of the field(since we have set replace count as `1`). This is to avoid replacement in anywhere else in the field.

(or) a more neater `awk` logic, thanks to [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) suggestion to use `gsub` on `$3` and store it on a variable as

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{next} 
  NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} 
  {k=$3; sub(/^\+/,"",k)} k in a{print; delete a[k]} 
      END{for(k in a) print k,a[k] > "unmatched"}' today main
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you please tell me how to change the TEXT SIZE ? , I am able to change color and bold by using below command.
  if      ($NF == "DELAYED")     {color="red"; bold=1; size=15}
  else if ($NF == "On_Time")     color="green"
  else if ($NF == "No_Records")  color="yellow"
  else                           color="#003abc"

  Dummy=$0
  sub("[^ ]+$","",Dummy)
  print Dummy "<span style=\"color:" color (bold ? ";font-weight:bold" : "") "\">" $NF "</span>"

Comment: @Janaranjan: Appreciate you find it helpful, you can post your new requirement as a separate question. It deserves a separate post than a comment